# C# is stringVariable = $"{integerVariableThatNeedsToBeAString}" better/faster than stringVariable = integerVariableThatNeedsToBeAString.ToString()

Tags: c#, string

The question is in the title, but is it the same/better/faster/worse to do:

```
var stringValue = intValue.ToString();
```

or

```
var stringValue = $"{intValue}";
```

Or should I not be thinking about such petty/unimportant things?

Comment: Mostly its should be in the unimportant category choose the one most readable for the context. But implementation wise they are different and the first one should be more optimal. Its just a conversion but the interpolated string comes with all the string.Format infrastructure that does more then needed even if unneeded here.

Comment: No, the second is slower. `string.Format` does much more, and some boxing is involved also